# Converting an SQL Containing inner and Outer Joins into Linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join, linq-to-sql

I need to convert an SQL query to Linq/Lambda expression, I am trying doing the same but not getting the desired results.

SQL:

```
 SELECT b.*, n.notes 
 FROM Goal_Allocation_Branch as b 
 INNER JOIN Goal_Allocation_Product as g 
      on b.Product = g.ProductID 
     and b.Year = g.Year 
 left join Goal_Allocation_Branch_Notes as n 
      on b.branchnumber = n.branch 
     and n.year = ddlYear
 WHERE b.Year = ddlYear 
   and g.Show = 1 
   and branchnumber = ddlBranch
```

I am new to Linq , I am getting error on Join Clause , and X is not containing any data from first Join

```
var result = (from br in _DB_Branches.Goal_Allocation_Branches
                          join pr in _DB_Product.Goal_Allocation_Products on  new { br.Product, br.Year } equals new {Product= pr.ProductID, Year= pr.Year }
                          join n in _DB_Notes.Goal_Allocation_Branch_Notes.Where(n => n.Year == ddlYear) on br.BranchNumber equals n.Branch into Notes
                          from x in Notes.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new BranchNotesViewModel
                          {
                              Year = x.Year,
                              BranchNumber = x.Branch,
                              ProductID = x.ProdID
                          }
                          ).ToList();
```

**Update:** My First Join clause initially giving error "The type of one of the expression in Join Clause is incorrect " is resolved, when I Changed On Clause
from

"on  new { br.Product, br.Year } equals new {pr.ProductID, pr.Year}"
"on  new { br.Product, br.Year } equals new {Product=pr.ProductID,Year= pr.Year}"

still not getting desired results as expected from above SQL query. Please advise..

Comment: So what have you tried and what are you stuck on?

Comment: Rather than duplicating the SQL you should try to use the navigation properties that linq-to-sql will create assuming that you have defined foreign keys for the joins you are attempting. https://coding.abel.nu/2012/06/dont-use-linqs-join-navigate/

Comment: Got your point juharr.. will try that way ..

Comment: No, I am still stuck.. Not able to figure out the how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the correct answer. Working absolutely fine

```
var result = (from br in _DB_Branches.Goal_Allocation_Branches
                          join pr in _DB_Product.Goal_Allocation_Products on new { br.Product, br.Year } equals new { Product = pr.ProductID, Year = pr.Year }
                          join n in _DB_Notes.Goal_Allocation_Branch_Notes.Where(n=>n.Year==ddlYear) on br.BranchNumber equals n.Branch into Notes
                          where br.Year==ddlYear 
                          && pr.Show== true
                          && br.BranchNumber==ddlBranch 
                          from x in Notes.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new BranchNotesViewModel
                          {
                             Year=x.Year,
                              BranchNumber=x.Branch,
                              ProductID=br.Product,
                              Notes = x.Notes, 
                             //All other fields needed
                           }
                          ).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this (see note):

```
var result = 
 (from br in _DB_Branches.Goal_Allocation_Branches
  join pr in _DB_Product.Goal_Allocation_Products
    on br.Product equals pr.ProductID
  from n in _DB_Notes.Goal_Allocation_Branch_Notes.Where(x=>
    x.branch == br.branchnumber
    && x.year == ddlYear
  ).DefaultIfEmpty()
  where
    br.Year == ddlYear 
    && and br.Year == pr.Year 
    && pr.Show == 1
    && br.branchnumber == ddlBranch
  select new BranchNotesViewModel
  {
    Year = ...,
    BranchNumber = ...,
    ProductID = ...
  }
 ).ToList();
```

Note: Change the select, to the properties you want.

Edit: fixed some syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks for response! But
 1)all alias br,n,pr etc. are giving error as they are being used before they declare or out of scope/context
2)in the select statements Year, Branch etc values are coming from where

Comment: I am sorry, I did not get that. Can you please explain or give example. Please guide.

Comment: Made some fixes, check now.